# SQL query exclude phrasing

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble with a SQL query, I can't think how to phrase it.

It's to pull a count of events from a log since you last checked it.

Currently I have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS alertcount, date AS alertdate 
FROM alerts WHERE to_id = '$id' AND date > '$lastcheck'
```

But, I want it to exclude all fields where `expire=1` and the `date` is over 30 mins old.

So if both of them expressions are true, it will ignore that record in the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS alertcount, date AS alertdate 
FROM alerts 
WHERE to_id = '$id' AND (date between '$lastcheck' and getdate() -30 minutes ) and expire!=1
```

I dont know your DB engine but if is SQL Server, use the `dateadd` function to calculate the `getdate() -30 minutes` expression

EDIT:
here is the condition with your new comment. not sure where the to_id will fit in this scenario and also you dont need a date parameter

```
WHERE ((expire=0) OR (date > getdate() -30 minutes and expire=1) )
```

Comment: thanks. so this will pull all fields from any date if expire is set to 0 yeah? and ones from last 30 mins where expire=1 ?

Comment: no, that's not exactly what u asked for. Do you want all fields with 0 plus all fields with 1 from the last 30 minutes?

Comment: yeah, that's what I need :) I'm using a mySQL db

Comment: needs the `AND date > '$lastcheck'` after `expire=0` but yeah, works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work (I am using SQL Server date-time functions)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS alertcount
,   date AS alertdate
FROM alerts
WHERE to_id = '$id' AND date > '$lastcheck'
AND (expire <> 1 OR dateadd(minute, -30, getdate()) < date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`HAVING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx), something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS alertcount, date AS alertdate 
FROM alerts 
WHERE to_id = '$id' AND date > '$lastcheck'
HAVING expire = 1 and DATEADD(minute, -30, GETDATE()) < yourDateField
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS alertcount, date AS alertdate 
FROM alerts WHERE to_id = '$id' AND date > '$lastcheck'
AND(expire<>1 AND DateDiff(MINUTE, [date]  , GETDATE())>30)
```